# Update a 2 tabelas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Não consigo fazer um update as 2 tabelas. O problemas está aqui.

```
  db.Entry(catequizando).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
```

Alguma solução?

*Controller*:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult Edit(CatequizandoCreateModel CatequizandoModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //criar um novo objeto para o model pessoa
            var pessoa = new Pessoa
            {
                Nome = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Nome,
                Morada = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Morada,
                Localidade = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Localidade,
                CodPostal = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.CodPostal,
                Telemovel = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Telemovel,
                Email = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Email,
                Genero = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Genero,
                Naturalidade = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Naturalidade,
                Nacionalidade = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Naturalidade,
                BI = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.BI,
                NIF = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.NIF,
                Estado_Civil = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Estado_Civil,
                Profissao = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Profissao,
                Habilitacoes_Literarias = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Habilitacoes_Literarias,
                DataNascimento = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.DataNascimento,
                Foto = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Foto,
                Observacoes = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Observacoes
            };
            //   criar um novo objeto para o model Catequizando
            var catequizando = new Catequizando
            {
                NomeEscola = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.NomeEscola,
                AnoEscolar = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.AnoEscolar,
                TurmaEscolar = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.TurmaEscolar,
                CedulaCrista = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.CedulaCrista,
            };
            db.Entry(catequizando).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CatequizandoID = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "PessoaID", "Nome", CatequizandoModel.CatequizandoID);
        return View(CatequizandoModel);
    }
```

Comment: Qual o problema que você está tendo?

Comment: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A abordagem está incorreta. Este erro que você está tendo:

> "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."

É quando a chave primária não está definida. Na verdade você deveria ter trazido os registros do banco e alterado eles. Não ter criado novos:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var pessoa = db.Pessoas.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PessoaId == CatequizandoModel.Pessoa.PessoaId);
        var catequizando = db.Catequizandos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.CatequizandoId == CatequizandoModel.Catequizando.CatequizandoId);

            pessoa.Nome = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Nome;
            pessoa.Morada = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Morada;
            pessoa.Localidade = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Localidade;
            pessoa.CodPostal = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.CodPostal;
            pessoa.Telemovel = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Telemovel;
            pessoa.Email = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Email;
            pessoa.Genero = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Genero;
            pessoa.Naturalidade = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Naturalidade;
            pessoa.Nacionalidade = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Nacionalidade;
            pessoa.BI = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.BI;
            pessoa.NIF = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.NIF;
            pessoa.Estado_Civil = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Estado_Civil;
            pessoa.Profissao = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Profissao;
            pessoa.Habilitacoes_Literarias = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Habilitacoes_Literarias;
            pessoa.DataNascimento = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.DataNascimento;
            pessoa.Foto = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Foto;
            pessoa.Observacoes = CatequizandoModel.pessoa.Observacoes;


            catequizando.NomeEscola = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.NomeEscola;
            catequizando.AnoEscolar = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.AnoEscolar;
            catequizando.TurmaEscolar = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.TurmaEscolar;
            catequizando.CedulaCrista = CatequizandoModel.catequizando.CedulaCrista;
        db.Entry(catequizando).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: Basicamente é isto, +1. Mas era evitado ele ter de fazer todas estas igualdades, certo?

Comment: `pessoa.Nome` está a null e o erro é: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Comment: @user10271 Aí você tem que verificar se as Ids estão vindo da tela. Pelo que você disse, não estão.

Comment: A `PessoaID` e `CatequizandoID` está sempre a 0.

Comment: @user10271 Então. Como eu te disse, você precisa escrever essas Ids na *View*. O MVC não tem como adivinhar que registro você está editando.

Comment: Pois claro.

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catequizando.CatequizandoID)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pessoa.PessoaID)`

Answer (score 3):

Se estás a criar uma `new Pessoa` e `new Catequizando` nunca podes fazer um `EntityState.Modified;`, porque basicamente os itens não existem.

Ou o elemento que estás a instanciar tem um `id` já existente, onde tens de colocar o `id` vindo do `CatequizandoModel`:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa
{
  id = CatequizandoModel.Pessoa.Id
  ...
}

var pessoa = new Catequizando
{
  id = CatequizandoModel.Catequizando.Id
  ...
}
```

Ou então guardas logo os dados do Model recebido:

```
db.Entry(CatequizandoModel.catequizando).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(CatequizandoModel.pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Optei pela ultima solução e dá erro no   `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: e que erro é? podes dizer

Answer (score 1):

Se você não precisa pegar os dados no banco de dados antes de realizar a alteração, você pode realizar o Attach antes de efetuar o SaveChanges, em alguns casos isso é muito bom para evitar I/O's.

```
//código que cria pessoa e catequizando.....

db.Pessoas.Attach(pessoa);
db.CatequizandosAttach(catequizando);
db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(catequizando).State = EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ainda não percebi muito bem o funcionamento do `Attach`.

Comment: @user10271 `Attach` é usado para indicar ao contexto que o objeto já foi carregado em algum outro lugar, mas eu particularmente considero essa abordagem perigosa porque você não tem como verificar por ela se o registro existe ou não em banco.

Comment: O Attach serve pra você vincular uma instância de objeto no contexto. Nesse cenário que ele apontou acima ao invés de ir no banco de dados pegar a pessoa via Single e alterar os campos, se ele tiver os valores da chave do objeto ele pode simples criar uma instancia do objeto passando a chave (campo ID por exemplo) "attachar" essa nova instância no contexto informar o contexto que essa instância foi alterada e dar um SaveChanges. O EF irá entender que os campos de um registro previamente cadastrado no banco de dados foi alterado e realizará o update.